# XMLStreamException while trying to parse an xml file downloaded from a ftp

Tags: java, xml, ftp

I am downloading a file from and ftp, saving it onto my local filesystem and then reading it with `createXMLStreamReader`. When I try and parse it I get this error:`javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[124,316]`. When I copy and paste it to another file manually everything works fine. I have tried copying the file using [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/copyfile.shtml), the file gets copied but I am still getting the same error. I do realize that this is caused because of binary characters before the `<xml` node but I am not sure on how to get rid of them.

I have no control over what is being copied from the ftp and I am using `java 1.7`

My code for retrieving the file:

```
client.connect("ftp.domain.com");
client.login("user", "password");

String filename = assetsPath + "/ftpExport.xml";
fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
client.retrieveFile("/Export.xml", fos);
```

My code to create the StreamReader:

```
inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
File f = new File(Parser.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
assetsPath = f.toString()+"/../assets";
xmlReader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(
    new FileReader(assetsPath + "/Export.xml"));
```

Comment: don't use a FileReader for reading xml as this can corrupt the file.  use a FileInputStream.

Comment: SWAHEEET that made it work. Can you put your comment as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use a FileReader for reading xml as this can corrupt the xml. use a FileInputStream.

Comment: why does a FileReader corrupts the file?

Comment: @Reddy - because xml, although it looks like text, is really a binary format.  the encoding is embedded in the xml header itself.  if you use a FileReader with the wrong encoding, then you will corrupt the xml.  you should _always_ treat xml data as bytes, not chars.